# spring security 5.1 oauth 2, how to add additional parameters to user authentication uri

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to integrate external oauth 2 authentication server and resource server. 
    Their configuration requires some additional custom parameters: state - should be uuid, TimeStamp, accessType, also clientSecret should be signed using a combination of all previous params as data.

We are using Spring boot, spring security 5.1, Camunda.

The catch is I can't directly add params to URI calling method setUserAuthorizationUri cause this method is called only once during initialization

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver** provides the ability to customize the Authorization Request with additional parameters above the standard parameters and/or removing/changing one of the standard parameters. See the reference doc on [OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2Client-authorization-request-resolver) for implementation details.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, Reference Documentation was the very first thing I checked out however for some reason, I've overlooked that section.

Comment: Helpful info, but why is "audience" not a standard parameter in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2Client-client-registration?