# Spring Security 5.3.2 OAuth 2, Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow - How to add additional HEADER parameters to authorization server uri

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to generate an access token from a custom corporate oauth 2 authorization server with Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3

This server only generate an access token if receive the following parameters:

```
POST https://custom_corporate_server/auth/oauth/v2/token

Header
idp: 99

Body
grant_type: password
scope: my_scope
client_id: 00******-****-****-****-**********99
client_secret: 00******-****-****-****-**********99
username: my_user
password: my_password
```

Their configuration requires additional header custom parameter: idp - should be a numeric.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.0 and Spring Security 5.3.2.

I followed the link bellow to build my test example:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#using-the-access-token-2

```
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                    .password()
                    .refreshToken()
                    .build();

    DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                    clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    // Assuming the `username` and `password` are supplied as `HttpServletRequest` parameters,
    // map the `HttpServletRequest` parameters to `OAuth2AuthorizationContext.getAttributes()`
    authorizedClientManager.setContextAttributesMapper(contextAttributesMapper());

    return authorizedClientManager;
}

private Function<OAuth2AuthorizeRequest, Map<String, Object>> contextAttributesMapper() {
    return authorizeRequest -> {
        Map<String, Object> contextAttributes = Collections.emptyMap();
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = authorizeRequest.getAttribute(HttpServletRequest.class.getName());
        String username = servletRequest.getParameter(OAuth2ParameterNames.USERNAME);
        String password = servletRequest.getParameter(OAuth2ParameterNames.PASSWORD);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(username) && StringUtils.hasText(password)) {
            contextAttributes = new HashMap<>();

            // `PasswordOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider` requires both attributes
            contextAttributes.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, username);
            contextAttributes.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, password);
        }
        return contextAttributes;
    };
}
```

I was unable to pass this parameter in the header to the authorization server. How to do this is my main dilemma today.

Comment: I think [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-oauth-requests) article explains your case pretty good.

Comment: @wjans thanks for the response, but [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-oauth-requests) dont apply for my case. I need to pass extra **HEADER parameters** for auth server. This another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890748/spring-security-5-1-oauth-2-how-to-add-additional-parameters-to-user-authentica/52900258#52900258) is similar, but it also doesn't apply to this case. Somebody help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-oauth-requests) article, it explains all kinds of customizations to authorization and token requests.  In your case, the section about [token request extra parameters](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-oauth-requests#extraToken), seems to describe exactly what you need.

You could do something like this:

```
public class CustomRequestEntityConverter implements Converter<OAuth2PasswordGrantRequest, RequestEntity<?>> {

    private OAuth2PasswordGrantRequestEntityConverter defaultConverter;

    public CustomRequestEntityConverter() {
        defaultConverter = new OAuth2PasswordGrantRequestEntityConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public RequestEntity<?> convert(OAuth2PasswordGrantRequest req) {
        RequestEntity<?> entity = defaultConverter.convert(req);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> params = entity.getHeaders();
        params.add("idp", "99");
        return new RequestEntity<>(params, entity.getHeaders(), entity.getMethod(), entity.getUrl());
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndréMicocci Also see the reference doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#customizing-the-access-token-request-4