# Spring Boot oauth2 dynamically add params to redirect url

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am using spring-security-oauth2-client. The redirect-uri in application.properties looks like this:

`spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.<client>.redirect-uri=https://custom-server.com/auth`

I need to dynamically add some information to the url, for example via a path parameter, just like this:
`https://custom-server.com/auth?id=123` or `https://custom-server.com/auth?id=321`

SecurityConfig is given below:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login/auth").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login();
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

is it possible to add params (request or path) to `redirect-url` depending on conditions?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890748/spring-security-5-1-oauth-2-how-to-add-additional-parameters-to-user-authentica) question what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you, @wjans! Yes, I solved this problem by implementing OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as @wjans mentioned, passing param to redirect-url possible by implementing `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver`:

```java
    public class CustomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolverimplements
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver {
    
      private static final String CUSTOM_PARAM = "id";
      private final OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver oAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver;
    
      public ConfigurableOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver oAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver) {
        this.oAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver = oAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver;
      }
    
      @Override
      public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest =
            this.oAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);
        return processAdditionalParameters(authorizationRequest);
      }
    
      @Override
      public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                String clientRegistrationId) {
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest =
            this.oAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request, clientRegistrationId);
        return processAdditionalParameters(authorizationRequest);
      }
    
      private OAuth2AuthorizationRequest processAdditionalParameters(OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest) {
        if (authorizationRequest == null) {
          return null;
        }
        String redirectUri = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromUriString(authorizationRequest.getRedirectUri())
            .queryParam(CUSTOM_PARAM, UUID.randomUUID())
            .build(true).toUriString();
        return OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.from(authorizationRequest)
            .redirectUri(redirectUri)
            .build();
      }
    }
```

and register that resolver as:

```java
    @Bean
      public OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver() {
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
                clientRegistrationRepository(),            
OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI
            );
        return new CustomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver);
      }
    
      @Bean
      public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            ...
            .oauth2Login()
            .authorizationEndpoint()
            .authorizationRequestResolver(
                authorizationRequestResolver());
    
        return http.build();
      }
```

Comment: I've been looking at this answer and I see the call to clientRegistrationRepository() on line 5. I'm assuming this method is calling another bean-initialiser method, but it took me a couple of minutes to realise it. Maybe adding it to the example will clarify this for the next person coming across this answer? It did help me fix my issue though, so thanks!